# What library do I need to use for HtmlWeb?

Tags: c#, web, libraries

This is my code:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
string CampUrl = "http://whois.domaintools.com/";
var campaign = web.Load(CampUrl);
var html = campaign.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

The problem is in this line:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
```

Comment: Did you even try to google `HtmlWeb`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like the HTML Agility Pack which you can download via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/).

You can learn more about it at [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/).

Comment: Isn't it better to add the Nuget-package for it?

Comment: @PChristianFrost It doesnt really matter. Using Nuget just allows you to update it easily in the case of an update.

Comment: @sara Put it where ever you want but you need to add the DLL as a reference to your project.

Comment: I added  the DLL as a reference. How I use it. Whats the code?

Comment: @CathalMF I'm quite sure that NuGet also autohandles references as well (and no need to wonder about which folder to put it in).

Comment: @PChristianFrost Yes true, it does.