# Auto clicking to a button on a webpage in C#

Tags: c#, function, web-scraping

So I have been trying to learn about web scraping and currently I am working on a website. In this website there is a more button which I have tried lots of ways to click it but somehow I couldn't figure out how.

```
      HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
      HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://example.com");
      IList<HtmlNode> nodes = doc.QuerySelectorAll("div.eexample");
```

I should add that this is a Controller.cs

I have searched about a function online but other than ".Click()" in Windows form application I couldn't find any information.

Comment: What scraping library are you using? [`HtmlWeb` looks like HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36570673/what-library-do-i-need-to-use-for-htmlweb), which is kinda old-and-busted now - consider using AngleSharp instead: https://anglesharp.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what front end frameworks the website you are trying to scrape are using you may need to use something for sophisticated than HTML Agility Pack or Angel Sharp. These libraries will not be able to execute the JavaScript on the pages you scrape. Modern websites often use frameworks that rely to dynamically request data from the server and update the page. Angel Sharp has some basic JavaScript functionality but may not work on very complex or dynamic sites using modern front end frameworks like Angular and React. Angel Sharp will work if you are trying to crawl pages and scrape content but not if you wish to interact with the page in a human like way. If you whish to interact with pages directly you will need to use some sort of browser automation e.g. [Selenium](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/) or [PlayWright](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Playwright).

These frameworks are capable of running full fledged browsers in headless mode that allow full interaction with both the DOM and JavaScript engine. In order to do this at scale you will need to build some resource pooling as you will only be able to have so many browser instances running at once depending on the amount of compute you have available. You will also need to implement strategies (rotating IP proxies, rotating user agents, session management) in your pool of browsers to prevent the site you are scraping from detecting multiple requests coming from the same location and blocking you. In essence you your scraping logic needs to act as much like a human as possible to avoid being detected and blocked. Hopefully this helps you get started.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium.
For example:
Install NuGet: Selenium-RC, Selenium.WebDriver.Chromedriver

```cs
using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(link); // link is the target url
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("Modal-closeButton")).Click(); //and find the element and click it.
        }
```